# nfs mount of mounted filesystem

Tags: mac-osx, mac, nfs, export

I have a volume exported:

```
/dev/disk5s2 on /Volumes/encrypted (hfs, NFS exported, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
```

The entry in the /etc/export is:

```
/Volumes/encrypted/paperwork -ro -fspath=/Volumes/encrypted
```

That volume is mounted by:

```
/usr/bin/hdiutil attach /Volumes/primary/encrypted/encrypted.dmg.sparsebundle
```

But from my client that does a simple:

```
 mount -t nfs -o vers=3,tcp,soft,noowners,rdonly "192.168.1.14:/Volumes/primary/encrypted/paperwork" "/Volumes/encrypted"
```

I get the error: "Permission denied".

Checked obvious things. I do have permission, showmount -e shows the mount point:

```
Airy:bin paulhargreaves$ showmount -e 192.168.1.14
Exports list on 192.168.1.14:
/Volumes/encrypted/paperwork        Everyone
```

What to do next to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtle whitespace error appeared to be the cause. Re-typing all the entries out and it worked.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.